# BeautifulSoup4: Getting just 3 lines of data instead of 12

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape the number of story headlines from Medium, but it's just giving me the top 3 only. But there are 12-13 instead.
Why?

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as req

resp = req.get('https://medium.com/@daranept27')

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

x = soup.select('A.eg.bv')
print(x)
```

I'm using `css selector` for it, cuz `XPATH` seems a pain to me for scraping every headline...
I don't want to use `selenium`, but I'd be interested to know if you have a reason for why it's not working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `requests_html` as `requests_html` has the ability to scrape dynamic content without using a `webdriver`. Here is the full code to do it:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://medium.com/@daranept27')
r.html.render()

x = r.html.find('a.eg.bv')
[print(elem.text) for elem in x]
```

Output:

```
Seven Days -Between Life And Death
Have you ever encountered a fake friend? If So, Try These Simple Tips To Overcome it.
Does Anybody Ever Wonder Why He’s My Everything?
Ladies, Why Should You Treat Your Face Like The Coloring Books?
Listen, Girl, Aren’t You Curious How The Last Line Could Be This Hurtful?
The girl name “Rich”
She Lost Her Beloved Mother, But Why She Asserted that Loss Was Not Just A Loss sometimes?
You Used To Try This Lonely. Have You Ever Imagine The flavor You Tried To Eat it with Your Lover?
If You Have Siblings, You Won’t Comprehend this. Have You Ever Wonder How A Child Feels Like? This Is How It Perceives.
Is It Okay To Help A Stranger?
The Nightmare Was Always Considered A Bad Omen, But It Turned Incredible Differently.
If You’re A Woman Or Girl Who Loves To Wear Lipstick, Read This Poetry.
She Wants To Spread This Poetry For Every Girl Or Woman That Was Born Just Like The Way She Was.
```

Comment: Heyy, thanks for the answer. But I got this error: 
`pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 8000 ms exceeded.`
Should I post the full error if you need?
(It also downloaded chromium btw)

Comment: Oh...Did it give u a timeout error? It worked fine for me. Try running the script again

Comment: It's giving me time out again and again at `r.html.render()`

Comment: Oh...I really don't have any idea why...It worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Many of them have faced the same prob. Can u try running this code after a while?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for looking this in, here's my question dedicated to this only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648747/python-requests-html-giving-me-timeout-error

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the page in question and it appears that some of the content dynamically load in after a couple of seconds or after you've clicked the *read more button*. This would explain why you only see the first three since those are the only ones loaded in when you scrape the page with BeautifulSoup.

BeautifulSoup does not, to my knowledge, have support for loading in those parts, in that case you would have to use something like Selenium or equivalent.

Comment: But the load more appears only after 5 to 6 posts not just 3... Or does it, when used request?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the html in response includes "script" and the content is dynamic. So you can use another library such as selenium to load the dynamic elements and then load the HTML to soup and follow the same steps below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=<yourdriver>)
url ='https://medium.com/@daranept27'
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

x = soup.select('a.eg.bv')
print(x)
```

Comment: Yeah I agree. Actually I've a same script too, but I want to know if it's possible without selenium???

Comment: Heyy, can scrapy do this??